# Request/Response messaging pattern in Amazon SQS

Tags: messaging, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I am using Spring boot + Amazon SQS
I have an scenario where I put a request into a queue, another component dequeues the message and needs to send a response back to the caller. For that, I was thinking put response in another queue so caller could get it.

My concern is: How do I check on caller side, that response I receive is related to my request ? As it is a multihtreading application , there could be several concurrent request, I in one particular thread I only want dequeue the response that is related to request in the thread and let the other threads dequeue their responses.

In JMS and RabittMQ  we have something like correlationId, DO you guys see any workaround ?

Thanks,
Deibys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS SQS Asynchronous Queuing Pattern (Request/Response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655685/aws-sqs-asynchronous-queuing-pattern-request-response)

Answer (score -1):

I was also looking for similar kind of feature.

Then i used **API Gateway** along with **AWS Lambda** as a workaround.
 Just check if it works for you. Also Note that Lambda has a timeout of 5 minute.