# Communication options for lambda instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am working on creating a lambda manager that interacts with other lambda instances.

The manager, which is also a lambda function will manage another lambda function that is executing a workload.

**edit:**
*I am trying to execute workloads on a lambdas as if they were in a VM to take advantage of the serverless pricing model, performance, and convenience. This is a research project inspired by the findings of a few recent research papers.*

This gives a quick overview of one of the papers: https://www.serverlesscomputing.org/wosc4/presentations/p7-wosc2018_lloyd_pdf_version.pdf

The manager will have the ability to:

- act as a keep alive function to allow the workload to persist
- destroy the lambda executing a workload (in python: call sys.exit())
- have some scheduling properties

and so my thinking is that I need a way to send a message or 
interact with that lambda instance.

**Methods for communicating between two lambda instances?**

I have tried using the Gateway API with websockets but that only lets me redirect to specific lambda functions, which is useful but not for the current problem.

I have looked at SNS, I think it can be done with SNS by creating a new topic and passing the arn to the invoked worker lambda but that seems ineffecient. The idea  came from here: [AWS SQS Asynchronous Queuing Pattern (Request/Response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655685/aws-sqs-asynchronous-queuing-pattern-request-response).

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you wish to do all this? Can you provide a use-case for why you wish to "manage another lambda function"? This is not a normal requirement for Lambda, so having an understanding of your higher-level purpose would make it easier to answer. Feel free to edit your Question to add more details.

Comment: As @JohnRotenstein already mentioned you need to provide a bit more details about what are you trying to achieve. For orchestration, you can use AWS Step functions. If you want to kill lambda you can use RequestResponse invocation and just drop the connection but it is realy ugly way and there must be a better solution for your use case then that.

Comment: You can even use cloud watch to communicate between lambdas.