# Request/Response Messaging for Cloudfoundry Apps with AWS SQS

Tags: microservices, cloud-foundry, amazon-sqs

I want to use AWS SQS for communication between my microservices (and later possibly SNS). Each microservice can have multiple instances up.

Currently I'm trying to implement the Request/Response pattern of message queues.
As I understand it, the normal way is to have one request queue, and pass a unique response queue per service instance.
The consuming service will process the message and send the response to the given response queue. Thus, the response will always be returned to the correct instance of the requesting service.

My problem now comes with Cloudfoundry.

How it should work:
Service A needs to request data from Service B.
There is one queue named `A-request-B`.
Service A starts with 6 instances.
Every instance creates its own queue: `B-response-A-instance[x]`
Every request from an instance of A sends their response queue name in the request so response is routed to the correct queue.

This is the only way I know to guarantee that the response from B gets to the correct instance of A.
This doesn't work as Cloudfoundry doesn't allow the "create-queue" call from SQS, even if I can connect to the SQS instance to send and receive messages.
The only way to create a queue is via the command line. 
So I would have to create these 6 response-queues manually beforehand.
And if I start a 7th instance of A, it will fail as it doesn't have its own response queue.

I also tried using the [SQS temporary queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-temporary-queues.html), but they also work by creating queues dynamically which is not possible in Cloudfoundry.

I'm currently stuck with SQS, so switching to kafka/rabbitmq or something else is not possible.

Is there any other way to pass a response to the matching service instance? Or is there another way to create queues in cloud foundry?

Comment: `My problem now comes with Cloudfoundry.` -> I don't understand. Can you expand on this more? How are you creating your service? How are you consuming the service? What would you like to do, but can't?

Comment: @DanielMikusa I updated the passage, hopefully it is clearer now what my problem is.

Comment: That does help, one follow up. What do you mean here? `This doesn't work as Cloudfoundry doesn't allow the "create-queue" call from SQS`. Cloud Foundry doesn't really care what messaging system you're using. What about this causes it to fail? What error do you see?

Comment: @DanielMikusa Cloud foundry handles the credentials to the AWS behind the queue. And the credentials CF gives you don't have the permission to create a queue. They are only allowed to send and receive messages for the specific queue you created.
And as far as I know there is no way to change the permissions or get  credentials with more rights.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're talking about the AWS Service broker? So you're doing `cf create-service` to provision your SQS service. If that's a problem, you could always provision your own SQS service info & creds, that have the perms you need. Then create a user provided service with that info. You can bind it to your apps just like a service created by the AWS Service broker. You'd lose the convenience of using the broker, but you wouldn't have to jump through the hoops you listed when scaling up/down.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Don't know why I didn't think of that. I forgot you could just connect to AWS without letting CF create the instance. I don't know if I can get access to the AWS but that's more a bureaucratic problem for me. 

Could this also work when I use  `cf create-service` to create my queue and then use `cf create-service key` to gain a key with more permissions? And pass this key on to my app?

Comment: I don't think it would work with a service key because the service broker is still going to create the resources on AWS and it would create those with less permissions. I suppose you could try it, but I'm not optimistic it would work. You have to go around the service broker to create the user with enough permissions. I'm just hypothesizing here, but perhaps you could create the service key then go into AWS and alter the permissions for the user that got created. The user would exist as long as the service key does, so you would only have to do that once per service key.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! You helped me a lot! Now I only need to argue with the AWS team to get the needed credentials.
If you want you can post the summary as answer so I can mark this question as answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS SQS Asynchronous Queuing Pattern (Request/Response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655685/aws-sqs-asynchronous-queuing-pattern-request-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments above...

> This doesn't work as Cloudfoundry doesn't allow the "create-queue" call from SQS

Cloud Foundry doesn't really care what messaging system you're using, unless you're using a Marketplace service to create it. In that case, Cloud Foundry will work on your behalf to create a service instance. It does this by talking to a service broker, which does the actual creation of the service instance and user credentials.

In your case, Cloud foundry handles creating the credentials to the AWS SQS through the AWS Service Broker. Unfortunately, the credentials the broker gives you don't have the permission to create queues. The creds are only allowed to send and receive messages for the specific queue that was created by the broker.

There's not a lot you can do about this, but there's a couple options:

1. Don't use the Marketplace service. Instead, just go to AWS directly, create an IAM user, create your SQS resources, and give the IAM user permissions to them.

   Then create a user provided service with the credentials and information for the resources you created. You can bind the user provided service to your apps just like a service created by the AWS Service broker. You'd lose the convenience of using the broker, but you won't have to jump through the hoops you listed when scaling up/down your app instances.
2. You could create a service instance through the broker, then create a service key. The service key is a long-lived set of credentials so you could then go into AWS, look up the IAM user associated with that service key and adjust the permissions so that you can create queues.

   You would then need to create a user provided service, like the first option, insert the credentials and information for your service key and bind the user provided service to any apps that you'd like to use that service.

   Don't delete the service key, or your modified user will be removed and your user provided service will stop working.

Hope that helps!