# How can I make request-response mode in AWS SQS in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have read this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simple-two-way-messaging-using-the-amazon-sqs-temporary-queue-client/ about using SQS as request response mode. It can be done via virtual queue.

But the SDK mentioned in this article is just for Java. There is no support for nodejs: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2981.

So is there any way I can use request-response mode in nodejs over SQS?

Comment: you probably want to look at the npm package: aws-sdk... searching on bing for `sqs nodejs`, the first hit brought up a guide.

Comment: I can find the library but it doesn't support temporary queue: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2981

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS SQS Asynchronous Queuing Pattern (Request/Response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655685/aws-sqs-asynchronous-queuing-pattern-request-response)

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao were you able to find any resolution around this? Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no support for temporary virtual sqs quesues in nodejs. The community is not planning to work on it in 2020 it seems.
Kindly refer [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-temporary-queues-client/issues/15) for tracking the issue.